# How to get string not starts with certain substring

Tags: regex

I tried to use `re.findall('^(?!a)b', 'xyzabbcdebt')` to select all `b` not starts with `a`.

I expect to have `['b', 'b']`.

However, it gives an empty array.

What is the correct regex?

Comment: Use a lookbehind, `r'(?<!a)b'`

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: `(?!a)` is a lookahead, you need a lookbehind. From the linked thread: "*Where `(?<!x)` means "only if it doesn't have "x" before this point".*"